# Update gridview from code behind in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I have gridview in my asp.net 3.5 application [C#]. Which looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="grid_table" ID="GridView1" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" ShowHeader="true"   
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" DataKeyNames="studentId" runat="server" 
        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
        OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" onrowupdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" 
        >

  <EmptyDataTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblNoRecord" runat="server" Text="No Record Found" ForeColor="Red"> </asp:Label>
  </EmptyDataTemplate>

</asp:GridView>
```

Now, In rowUpdating event, I am writing the below code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int mytext = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
    string cConatiner = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
}
```

In this, myText is giving me the correct value, i.e. of the 1st column but when I am changing the cell value to 1,2,3,4,5,6 I am getting empty.

Am I doing it incorrectly ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help, I am Unable to find the solution

Comment: As i got your cConatiner is always empty. Is it Your problem? Did you check data fetched from DB/(other source)?

Comment: I am binding my gridview from dataset, and gridview is showing 9 columns and 16 rows, I am unable to get the value of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are setting a cell's value with the value of mytext.  I am going to assume you are try to set Cell[4]'s value in the code below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int mytext = Convert.ToInt16(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
    string cConatiner = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;

    GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text = mytext;
}
```

If Cell[4] isn't want cell you're setting, change appropriately.